# PHP GD - Color Replacement with Alpha gives images a border

Tags: php, gd

I am not sure if the function below works for the most part or not at all. What i am trying to is loop through the pixels and switch the color while maintaining the alpha. I thought I had it working till I made my page background white and saw a small border around the icon.

I thought that the problem was that the color was being applied to a semi transparent pixel. Thus white turned grey into lighter grey on the anti-aliased parts of the images. I decided then to make the pixel completely transparent before setting the new color. This did nothing.

So the question. Why do white images have a small border?

The color conversion function.

```
function updateThumb($image, $newColor) {
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($image);

    $w = imagesx($img);
    $h = imagesy($img);

    // Work through pixels
    for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++) {
        for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++) {
            // Apply new color + Alpha
            $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, imagecolorat($img, $x, $y));

        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagesetpixel($img, $x, $y, $transparent);

            $pixelColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, $newColor[0], $newColor[1], $newColor[2], $rgb['alpha']);
            imagesetpixel ($img, $x, $y, $pixelColor);
        }
    }

    // Restore Alpha
    imageAlphaBlending($img, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($img, true);

    return $img;
}
```

Thumbs need a rollover effect so the image is made in the function below. I don't believe this has anything to do with the issue, I have tried changing the above function to create the image and not return it and the same thing happens.

```
function makeThumb($path, $top, $bottom=FALSE) {
    $width = imagesx($top);
    $height = imagesy($top);

    $thumbHeight = $bottom != FALSE ? $height * 2 : $height;

    // Create Transparent PNG
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $thumbHeight);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumb, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($thumb, 0, 0, $transparent);

    // Copy Top Image
    imagecopy($thumb, $top, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);

    // Copy Bottom Image
    if ($bottom != FALSE) {
        imagecopy($thumb, $bottom, 0, $height, 0, 0, $width, $height);
    }

    // Save Image with Alpha
    imageAlphaBlending($thumb, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($thumb, true);
    imagepng($thumb, $path); // save image as gif

}
```

functions are called like this...

```
$thumbTop = updateThumb('Path/To/Thumb', array(255,255,255));
makeThumb('output/path', $thumbTop);
```

This is the icon: http://img171.imageshack.us/i/iconkc.png/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

OMG THANK YOU FOR THIS BIT OF CODE!!!! :D There is somone else i have to thank also, but I cannot find their code on this site sadly. I took, your code and the other guy's code and merged them. I've noticed that you save the image, I haven't figured out how to saved the colored image other then right click and save via the browser, however, the image will change color.

```
    function updateThumb($image, $newColor) {
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($image);

    $w = imagesx($img);
    $h = imagesy($img);

    // Work through pixels
    for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++) {
        for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++) {
            // Apply new color + Alpha
            $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, imagecolorat($img, $x, $y));

            $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
            imagesetpixel($img, $x, $y, $transparent);


            // Here, you would make your color transformation.
            $red_set=$newColor[0]/100*$rgb['red'];
            $green_set=$newColor[1]/100*$rgb['green'];
            $blue_set=$newColor[2]/100*$rgb['blue'];
            if($red_set>255)$red_set=255;
            if($green_set>255)$green_set=255;
            if($blue_set>255)$blue_set=255;

            $pixelColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, $red_set, $green_set, $blue_set, $rgb['alpha']);
            imagesetpixel ($img, $x, $y, $pixelColor);
        }
    }

    // Restore Alpha
    imageAlphaBlending($img, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($img, true);

    return $img;
}

function makeThumb($path, $top, $bottom=FALSE) {
    $width = imagesx($top);
    $height = imagesy($top);

    $thumbHeight = $bottom != FALSE ? $height * 2 : $height;

    // Create Transparent PNG
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $thumbHeight);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumb, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($thumb, 0, 0, $transparent);

    // Copy Top Image
    imagecopy($thumb, $top, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);

    // Copy Bottom Image
    if ($bottom != FALSE) {
        imagecopy($thumb, $bottom, 0, $height, 0, 0, $width, $height);
    }

    // Save Image with Alpha
    imageAlphaBlending($thumb, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($thumb, true);
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($thumb, $path); // save image as png

}

$thumbTop = updateThumb('input/path', array(240,105,15));
makeThumb('output/path', $thumbTop);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this! You inspired me to use a pixel by pixel way in an image worker i'm building.
At first i had the same problem you had but i think i figured out how to fix it.

**Problem**

it seems to me as if `imagesetpixel` does not replace the pixel with the new rgba values but instead puts them OVER the old ones.

**Solution**

```
function updateThumb($image, $newColor) {
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($image);

    $w = imagesx($img);
    $h = imagesy($img);

    // create a new blank image.
    $target = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($target, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($target, 0, 0, $transparent);

    // Work through pixels
    for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++) {
        for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++) {
            // Apply new color + Alpha
            $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, imagecolorat($img, $x, $y));

            // and set the new color to the blank image.
            $pixelColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($target, $newColor[0], $newColor[1], $newColor[2], $rgb['alpha']);
            imagesetpixel($target, $x, $y, $pixelColor);
        }
    }

    // Restore Alpha
    imageAlphaBlending($target, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($target, true);

    return $target;
}
```

**What went wrong:**

```
// new image
$target = imagecreatetruecolor(1, 1);

// Set a Pixel
$pixelColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($target, 0, 0, 0, 60);
imagesetpixel($target, 0, 0, $pixelColor);

// "Replace" The Pixel
$pixelColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($target, 255, 255, 255, 60);
imagesetpixel($target, 0, 0, $pixelColor);

// See the rgba values of the pixel
var_dump(imagecolorsforindex($target, imagecolorat($target, 0, 0)));
```

Expected:

```
array(4) {  
    ["red"]=> int(255)  
    ["green"]=> int(255)  
    ["blue"]=> int(255)  
    ["alpha"]=> int(60)  
}
```

Actual:

```
array(4) {  
    ["red"]=> int(174)  
    ["green"]=> int(174)  
    ["blue"]=> int(174)  
    ["alpha"]=> int(28)  
}
```

Comment: Was struggling with the same problem until I found this. Thanks!